# Verify Binaries

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, hash-verification

I am getting stuck verifying the SHA256 hash for the binary I downloaded.
I moved the binary to the download directory and did cd Downloads and this is what I get. What is going wrong here? Im using Tails.

```
amnesia@amnesia:~/Downloads$ shasum -a 256 monero-linux-x64-v0.17.1.1.tar.bz2
shasum: monero-linux-x64-v0.17.1.1.tar.bz2: No such file or directory
```

Comment: It's telling you the file is not there ("No such file or directory"). `ls` will show you the files in the current directory.

Comment: thanks. I did that and copied and pasted it. Im not sure why copying from the file properties didnt work.